Publish NPM package to local Gitlab registry
I got windows server which runs CI/CD jobs for my projects. Now I want to add NPM package that I will use locally. I found this manual and that tutorial, but I'm stuch attempting to publish using a CI/CD pipeline (8:31 at video)
What I got at the moment is such  .gitlab-ci.yml file:
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy

publish-npm:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo '@<scope>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/' > .npmrc
    - echo '//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/:_authToken="gldt-<...>"' >> .npmrc
    - npm publish

Also tried this:
    - echo '@<scope>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/' > .npmrc
    - npm config set //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/:_authToken gldt-<...>

What I got during CI/CD is:
$ npm publish 
...                                   
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

And that's the problem
But what makes me confused is if I hardcode .npmrc to the root with content:
@<scope>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/:_authToken="gldt-<...>"

and update .gitlab-ci.yml accordingly:
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy

publish-npm:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm publish

Then no errors occur. In both cases content of .npmrc files just prior to npm publish is the same (checked with type .npmrc command)
UPD #1 I do not want to place Deploy token neither .npmsrc nor '.gitlab-ci.yml' files, so I found a solution which works at least. My '.npmrc' looks lie:
@<scope>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/

with new line in the end, and '.gitlab-ci.yml' looks like:
image: node:latest
    
    stages:
      - deploy
    
    publish-npm:
      stage: deploy
      script:
        - echo "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=""${My_Deploy_token}""" >> .npmrc
        - npm publish

And if I type .npmrc prior to npm publish, it give such result:
@<scope>:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/
/ / g i t l a b . c o m / a p i / v 4 / p r o j e c t s / < p r o j e c t   i d > / p a c k a g e s / n p m / : _ a u t h T o k e n = " g l d t - < . . . >"

Yes, with that mush spaces in the end of the line, but at least it works. I suppose problem is in encodings or something related on my server OR how I excape "
UPD #2 Find out that package updated without that command :
- echo "//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=""${My_Deploy_token}""" >> .npmrc

I guess that's might be because I previously run lot of times npm config set ...
